# What is the best solution to read whole sheet to VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, range

**EDITED BODY**

I have a sheet that have Document type, Vendor #, Vendor name etc. columns. Somehow I have to read the whole sheet to a Range,Array,Collection I don't know this is why asking this.

So I planning to read the whole data to the memory and taking tasks like  analyse the inv. reference length, change values etc. After that write the results to another sheet.

First thoughts was create a Class with types Invoice number and every columname. After that read the whole sheet by row and add to a list every created object but I dont know this is the fastest and easiest way..

Comment: `Dim myArray as Variant: Set myArray = myRange.Value`, where `myRange` is a valid `Range` object  reference. For instance: `myarray = Range("A1", Cells(Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp)).Value` to get all column A cells from row 1 down to last not empty one values

Comment: Pretty much what @HTH said. However, if you need pure speed `.Value2` property would be faster for accessing certain types of data (numbers in particular). Have a look here --> https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/11/30/text-vs-value-vs-value2-slow-text-and-how-to-avoid-it/

Comment: Do you have the array bit, but you wish to reference what would have been column C for example?

Comment: Ohh sorry not necessary to read it to an array. I want to find the best solution(data type) to get the whole range and working with it. So inside the macro I have to filter and delete/changes value and after that write to a result sheet.

Comment: @Dev, and still arrays can be your friend. But your question, I'm afraid, is much **too broad** …(aaarrrgghh!)

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure to declare the array variable you want to store the data **as a Variant**.

Example:

```
Dim My_Data as Variant    
My_data = Worksheets("Sheet_Name").Range("A1:D100").value
```